# Probability of the derangement

Tags: probability

There are $n$ participants in a meeting and we prepare an urn in which we put their
name cards in it. Before the conference starts, the participants need to register themselves by picking up a name card at random from the urn.
Consider $1\leq m \leq n$ and find the probability $q_{n,m}$ that exactly $m$ participants find his or her own name card. When $m$ is fixed and $n \to \infty$, what is the limit of $q_{n,m}$?

So far I understand the number of derangements of $n$ objects is [$\frac{n!}{e}$], but I have trouble solving the above question. Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: This involves [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)

Comment: When $m \ll n$, the probability $q_{n, m}$ (with fixed $n$) approximately follows a Poisson distribution with mean $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the $m$ participants that will find their own name card, then derange the rest. So
$$q_{n,m} = \frac{\binom{n}{m} \left[ \frac{(n-m)!}{e} \right]}{n!}$$

To see what happens as $n \to \infty$, note that one way to derive the formula for derangements you gave comes from using inclusion-exclusion:

$$\begin{align}
D_n &= \frac{n!}{0!} -  \frac{n!}{1!} +  \frac{n!}{2!} + \cdots +(-1)^n \frac{n!}{n!} \\[2mm]
&= n! \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \right) \; \to \; \frac{n!}{e} 
\end{align}$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Then as $n \to \infty$,

$$\begin{align}
 q_{n,m} &\to \frac{\binom{n}{m} \frac{(n-m)!}{e}}{n!} = \frac{1}{m!\,e}
\end{align}$$